# Proguard :Exclude library project in Android

Tags: android, proguard

I have two projects Project_A and Project_B. Project_B is library project for Project_A. Project_B has external jar in its libs folder.

When i run proguard on Project_A, I get errors as:

```
(Unknown verification type [69] in stack map frame))
```

The error refers to the file present in external jar(which is present in libs of Project_B)

I am using standard proguard.cfg file that we get in android SDK.

I have tried "-keep class .**" but still i am getting same error.

Please let me know if there exists a way by which I can exclude Project_B(library project) and its jars from obfuscating. I want to run proguard only on Project_A , not on its library project.

Comment: http://tools.android.com/recent/proguardimprovements. check the example @ http://proguard.sourceforge.net/index.html#manual/examples.html

Answer (score 0):

ProGuard needs the entire class hierarchy to properly process the application, so you can't really leave out the library.

The library code appears to be corrupt; most likely, it has been post-processed by a tool that has corrupted it. Some tools don't update the verification information properly. This information is optional, but ProGuard expects it to be properly formed. You should check if there is a more recent version of the library or of the post-processing tool.

Comment: I used shade plugin to merge into single jar.I'm getting the same erro, ProGuard pointing to an internal class of one of external library saying "Unknown verification type [73] in stack map frame"